# Is it possible to do an unsafe covariant invocation of a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a number of classes designed to handle objects of specific types.

e.g.,

```
class FooHandler : Handler<Foo> {
   void ProcessMessage(Foo foo);
}
```

where the handler interface might be defined something like this:

```
interface Handler<T> {
   void ProcessMessage(T obj);
}
```

Now, I'd like to be able to use a dictionary of these handlers:

```
Dictionary<Type, Handler> handlers;

void ProcessMessage(object message) {
   var handler = handlers[message.GetType()];
   handler.ProcessMessage(handler);
}
```

However, C# doesn't appear to allow me to use the Handler interface without specifying a type. C# also doesn't allow me to declare `interface Handler<out T>` so I can't use `Handler<object>` in the handlers declaration.

Even this doesn't work:

```
Dictionary<Type, object> handlers;

void ProcessMessage(object message) {
   dynamic handler = handlers[message.GetType()];
   handler.ProcessMessage(message);
}
```

This seems to be solvable using reflection:

```
handler.GetType().GetMethod("ProcessMessage").Invoke(handler, new object[] { message });
```

And, of course, I could remove the generics from the Handler interface. However, the reason I went down this path is that I wanted to make the API for handlers as simple as possible. I wanted classes to specify the messages they receive and for them to be able to process those messages without having to cast the parameters in every method.

I'd prefer to avoid reflection if possible and avoiding generics altogether doesn't quite seem satisfactory.

Am I missing something obvious or am I pushing up against the limits of C#'s generics?

I realize that C# isn't Java (with Java's type erasure, this would be easy) and perhaps this might have been better solved in a more C#-like way... so I'm also interested in other approaches.

Thanks!

Comment: I find the ability to supply any arbitrary type as a "message" to be rather suspect. I mean, how can an `object` or `Point` be a message? I'd refactor so all the possible messages share an interface, say, `IMessage`. I'd also make the code a bit clearer, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I am using a base interface `IMessage`, but I left out such details for simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a better way.  Just embed the cast in a lambda and store the action rather than the handler:

```
    Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> handlers;

    void AddHandler<T>( Handler<T> handler )
    {
        handlers.Add(typeof(T), m => handler.ProcessMessage((T)m));
    }

    void ProcessMessage(object message)
    {
        var handler = handlers[message.GetType()];
        handler(message);
    }
```

OK, this goes beyond the scope of the question a bit, but the discussion in the comments led us here:

```
interface IMessage {}

class Foo : IMessage {}

interface Handler<T> where T : IMessage
{
    void ProcessMessage(T obj);
}

class FooHandler : Handler<Foo>
{
    public void ProcessMessage(Foo foo) {}
}

class Program
{
    static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

    static void AddHandler<T>(Handler<T> handler) where T : IMessage
    {
        handlers.Add(typeof(T), m => handler.ProcessMessage((T)m));
    }

    static void ProcessMessage(object message)
    {
        var handler = handlers[message.GetType()];
        handler(message);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypes()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetDerivedFrom<T>()
    {
        return GetAllTypes().Where(t => IsDerivedFrom(t, typeof(T)));
    }

    static bool IsDerivedFrom(Type t, Type parent)
    {
        return parent.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t!=parent;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var handlerTypes =
            from handlerBaseType in GetDerivedFrom<IMessage>().Select(t => typeof(Handler<>).MakeGenericType(t))
            select GetAllTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => IsDerivedFrom(t, handlerBaseType))
            into handlerType
            where handlerType!=null
            select Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);

        foreach (object handler in handlerTypes)
        {
            AddHandler((dynamic)handler);
            Console.WriteLine("Registered {0}.", handler.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

No strings involved...  Of course, if you want to establish the convention by naming you could make the scanning easier and simply look up the handler type from the name of the message type as done in your comment.  You could also replace the Activator.CreateInstance with an IOC container.

Comment: Like it. This is a nice approach. I was taking the dictionary form as a given, but there's no reason it should be.

Comment: Thanks! And based on Ben's latest comment I would replace object with IMessage.

Comment: I think the disadvantage of this approach is that it requires either the handlers to register themselves using AddHandler or for the list of possible handlers to be known in advance so that the list of handlers can be populated. Jon Skeet's approach would allow handlers to be loaded dynamically, without requiring that the handlers have any self-registration logic.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how the list of handlers gets populated would be the same for all these solutions, right?   I'm not seeing it that its different - it casts to Handler<T> so you have to at least know that to register them.

Comment: @jdasilva --- your last comment my be related to the edit in my answer.

Comment: But I don't think you can talk about Handler<T> in a generic sense. So you couldn't do something like `var handler = Type.GetType(String.Format("Handlers.{0}Handler", m.GetType().Name)).GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(null); AddHandler(handler);` (but then I'm using reflection here anyway, so am kind of undermining my own question)

Comment: @Ben: Yes, the only difference is when the registration process only knows about the `T` as a `Type` rather than in a static way. But then you could use the same dynamic idea as in my answer for *registration*, but jdasilva's solution for *execution* which may be more efficient.

Comment: Jon, could you explain? I can't see how you can use dynamic for registration in a way that would not also involve a dynamic invocation on each execution.

Comment: I think he's suggesting that you replace var with dynamic in your code above and then the AddHandler call will use the actual type to register allowing you to use what I posted.

Comment: @jdasilva Attempting to do that will raise a RuntimeBinderException.

Comment: @Ben, Is the type of the message you want to add the handler for known at compile time?

Comment: The possible message types are equally known to the compiler as are the handlers; I'd think of it in much the same way as the answer by Eben Roux (i.e. an Enterprise Service Bus). In theory, I'd like to be able to add or delete message types and handler's *.cs files, hit compile and it will work (without an implicit contract that each message and handler needs to register itself). If all the message types were known, then we could have declared concrete `AddHandler(Handler<Foo> x)` and `AddHander(Handler<Bar> x)` methods so that `AddHandler((dynamic)handler)` registration will work (but alas).

Comment: @Ben, I added a sample with dynamic registration.

Comment: @Ben, got your e-mail - what an unexpected and pleasant surprise - thank you!

Comment: @jdasilva thanks for sharing this code.  Very handy.  btw: do you prefer dynamic or object for this kind of thing?  Your cast from object method on the surface seems faster, but perhaps there's not much in it.

Comment: @sgtz In my experience doing a cast like that is very fast as is the small lambda, and almost sure to beat dynamic.  Dynamic is also very [expensive the first time](http://www.codethinked.com/c-40-new-features-part-11-dynamic-keyword-second-look) and although the situation is better than the article in RTM, I've still found the first hit of a dynamic keyword to be rough (at least when starting up a desktop app).  I've found that little lambdas like this perform extremely well.

Comment: @jdasilva that's good to know about the first hit + performance difference.  ty.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that dynamic typing will work if you take it one step further:

```
void ProcessMessage(dynamic message) {
   dynamic handler = handlers[message.GetType()];
   handler.ProcessMessage(message);
}
```

Note how I've made `message` dynamic, so that the overload resolution will be applied using the *actual* type of the object, rather than with `object`.

Basically what you're trying to do isn't statically type-safe, which is why the C# compiler isn't letting you get away with it. This is fairly typical in situations where you only have a `Type` value at execution time.

One other option is to have a generic method yourself and execute *that* either with reflection or dynamic:

```
void ProcessMessage(dynamic message)
{
    // This will call the generic method with the right
    // type for T inferred from the actual type of the object
    // message refers to.
    ProcessMessageImpl(message);
}

void ProcessMessageImpl<T>(T message)
{
    Handler<T> handler = (Handler<T>) handlers[typeof(T)];
    handler.ProcessMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: interesting. I was wondering where I could use dynamic.  Would this infer that the source must be passed in as dynamic, and not as an object?  Or, does dynamic dynamically interpret what is inside an object?

Comment: @sgtz: Any type is implicitly convertible to dynamic, basically. But see my edit from just now - I've been trying to save it for ages, but with no 3G signal :(

Comment: +1 @Jon: nice solution.  I think I'll delete my answer from below.  If we could dynamically deserialize life would be easier again.  Normally we deserialize<T> here

Comment: I'd be curious to know at 4 votes to 1 why a solution with dynamic would be preferred over what I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You have your solution in using reflection :)

That is the only way I am aware of to do this.  I am using this exact approach in my ESB.

---

**EDIT**

There is a caveat in using the other approaches (I may be wrong so please comment if I'm off track).  It is fine when you are registering a 'singleton' handler with the known message type up-front.  Using a generic `<T>` means you know the type.  However, in my scenario I use transient handlers depending on the message type that arrives.  So I create a new handler.

This means that everything has to be done on-the-fly thus requiring reflection (except maybe using `dynamic` in .net 4 --- I'm on .net 3.5).

Ideas?

Comment: @sgtz --- the example is in Ben's question :)

Comment: Would this work?

`        void AddHandler<THandler,TMessage>() where THandler : Handler<TMessage>, new()
        {
            handlers.Add(typeof(TMessage), m => new THandler().ProcessMessage((TMessage)m));
        }`

Comment: I don't think so.  I don't have a `handlers` collection.  I have a handler factory that creates a *new* handler based on the received message type; so I use `Activator.CreateInstance`.  I cannot use `<T>` since I don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: Do you look up the handler's type based on some convention as you receive the messages?  Are you constructing the handler every time or on the first message of a particular type?

Comment: Well, it depends on the factory implementation.  But basically the factory holds a list of message types along with the handler type for the relevant message type (so `Dictionary<Type, Type> messageHandlerTypes`).  When I receive a message type I get the handler type and new one up and call the `ProcessMessage` method and pass in a `HandlerContext<T>` (T being the message type).

Comment: @Eben, Take a look at the sample I added it might offer you some interesting ideas.  I can't remember 3.5's limits but if its capable then I'm pretty sure the dynamic could be replaced with a lambda expression.  In your case you could also compile a lambda expression based on the type that called the constructor as well and register that as the handling action. If you have cases where you construct per message I think that would result in a massive perf difference.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing an impementation of Jon's idea which is shared here.

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void ProcessMessage(dynamic message);
}

public class Handler<T> : IHandler
{
    public void ProcessMessage(dynamic message)
    {
    }
}

public class A{} public class B{} public class C{} public class D{}

public class HandlerA : IHandler{
    public void ProcessMessage(dynamic message){}
}

public class HandlerB  : IHandler{
    public void ProcessMessage(dynamic message) {}
}

public class HandlerC  : IHandler{
    public void ProcessMessage(dynamic message) {}
}

public class MsgProcessor
{
    public Dictionary<Type, IHandler> handlers = new Dictionary<Type, IHandler>();

    public void AddHandler<T>(T o) where T: IHandler
    {
        handlers.Add(typeof(T),o);
    }

    public void ProcessMessage(dynamic message)
    {
        ProcessMessage(message);
    }

    public void ProcessMessage<T>(T message)
    {
        Handler<T> handler = (Handler<T>) handlers[typeof (T)];
        handler.ProcessMessage(message);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void test()
    {
        var mp = new MsgProcessor();
        mp.AddHandler<HandlerA>(new HandlerA());
        mp.AddHandler<HandlerB>(new HandlerB());
        mp.AddHandler<HandlerC>(new HandlerC());

        mp.ProcessMessage(new A());
        mp.ProcessMessage(new B());
        mp.ProcessMessage(new C());

    }
}
```